# shift left bits value in c

Tags: c, microcontroller

## update

I'm new at hardware programming with c compiler for the PIC 18F4550 from Microchip.

My question is, can someone give me an example 'how to shift bits left with a carry' 1110 => 14?

The bit is a flag somewhere to go. also the number should be reduced to that a bit. I hope that's clear, sorry in advance!

`unsigned int red = 1206420333240;
LATAbits.LATA2 = red << 1;`

Comment: Where are the bits coming from? An array of ints with exclusevily  `0` and `1` for values? In reverse order (low bit at low address)?

Comment: ... No, it is entirely unclear to me.  Start again.

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry!

Comment: Please give us a complete example, including input, output and a small description.

Answer (score 0):

Untested basic version

```
unsigned result = 0;
index = 0;
while (1) {
    if (result > UINT_MAX / 2) /* there will be carry on the next operation! */;
    result *= 2;
    result += data[index];
    index++;
    /* this loop needs a break somewhere */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear to me.

Do you wish to know how to shift left the whole array, where each integer represent a bit (example: {0,0,1,0}=>{0,1,0,0}?
If you do, you can try the following (assumption: array is not empty):

```
int i;
int arraySize = sizeof(data) / sizeof(int); // You can change sizeof(int) with sizeof(data[0])
int carry = data[0];
for (i = 1; i < arraySize; i++)
   data[i - 1] = data[i];
```